# Stop Tensorflow from reloading model per request

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I've inherited some TF code that does the following per request:

```
def predict_tf(ml_wrapper, prediction_row_df):
    log.debug('request POST {}'.format(prediction_row_df))

    prediction_row_df, _, _ = ml_wrapper._engineer_features(prediction_row_df)
    # As method says; delete stuff we don't want and scale and impute if needed
    ml_wrapper._delete_unused_values_and_scale_and_impute_missing_values(prediction_row_df, single_row_prediction=True)
    features, labels = ml_wrapper._split_features_and_labels(prediction_row_df)
    panda_function_for_prediction = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        features,
        labels,
        batch_size=ml_wrapper.batch_size,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False
    )
    predictions = ml_wrapper.tf_model.predict(
        input_fn=panda_function_for_prediction)
    probas = list(predictions)[0]['probabilities']
    log.warning('PREDICTED: no:{} yes:{}'.format(probas[0], probas[1]))
    return probas
```

The code appears to work, though in console I see something like this:

```
2018-06-06 16:32:46,767 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Calling model_fn.
2018-06-06 16:32:50,848 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Done calling model_fn.
2018-06-06 16:32:51,082 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Graph was finalized.
2018-06-06 16:32:51,083 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Restoring parameters from /model_tensorflow/model.ckpt-719
2018-06-06 16:32:51,494 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Running local_init_op.
2018-06-06 16:32:51,536 INFO  [tensorflow:116] Done running local_init_op.
```

This operation seems to take 4s per request - is there a way to load the model/estimator just once and predict on it?

Comment: Can you identify where the tensorflow model gets loaded from the protobuf? I assume it's in one of the `ml_wrapper` method calls.

You should definitely be able to load the model once-off outside of the  `predict_tf` endpoint call.

Comment: `self.tf_model = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(model_dir=self.model_dir, ...)
`
 - this is called way earlier in the application lifecycle (on application start), and I expected it would load the data - but it seems the model is reloaded per predict() call.

Comment: I see. The reloading really shouldn't be necessary (the object doesn't get re-initialized, does it?)  but I can't say more without digging into the `ml_wrapper` and app body. I'd do line profiling on `predict_tf`, then drill down from there. Sorry not to have anything clearer; perhaps someone else will.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem, https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/rOP4VKcfphg and it is not related to the flow of my code I think. I'm struggling with the generator approach though :(

Comment: Maybe this solves it? https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/serving-tensorflow-estimator.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Estimator` then you can try this one:
https://github.com/marcsto/rl/blob/master/src/fast_predict2.py
This basically prevents reloading the graph.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment. If you feel it could answer the question, then please provide how the Asker should modify their code to make it work as desired.